# Rendering UIView to image when view draws outside its bounds

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to render a UIView to an image. My go-to UIView category for this is

```
- (UIImage *)num_renderToImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

However in this case, the UIView has elements that draw outside its bounds and the above clips them. Altering the size passed to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` doesn't help since the size grows down and to the right, but these elements are above and to the left. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you Include photos of what's happening, and what you want?

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me attach images yet (not enough rep points…). But imagine you have a UIView with bounds (0,0,100,100). Now imagine one of its subviews is a button with frame (-10,-10,20,20). So the button hangs off the top left corner of the view. As long as the enclosing UIView doesn't clip its bounds, everything is fine. But if you want to render that view (along with the button) to a UIImage using the above code, the part of the button that draws outside of the view won't be included in the render. Hope that makes sense sans-photos.

Comment: Wild shot in the dark: Have you tried setting `clipsToBounds=NO` on your UIView?

Comment: do you want to render the view which is not visible(out of bounds from screen)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the scenario above, with a `UIView` clipping a `UIButton` that draws outside its bounds, you might try:

```
- (IBAction)snapshot:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = sender;
    UIView *v = button.superview;

    // Prepare the rectangle to be drawn
    CGRect allTheViews = CGRectUnion(v.bounds, button.frame);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(allTheViews.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // This is what you differently
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -allTheViews.origin.x, -allTheViews.origin.y);

    // This part is the same as before
    [v.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile:@"/tmp/foo.png" atomically:NO];
}
```

Here we're taking the union of what we want to draw, then translating the CTM so it's in view in the graphics context we're drawing into.

(This example, in particular, is hooked up to the action of the button and writes the `UIImage` of the button and containing view out to a file. You can adjust as your needs require.)

Comment: Yep, that's it. The key is to translate the context with CGContextTranslateCTM since you can only control the size, not the 'origin' as such.

Answer (score 0):

I made this more general version in Swift 5.0 if anyone has the problem. Just set the offset to the value you want :

```
private func snapshotView(cell:UIView) -> UIImageView
{
        // by how much extra point out of the view bounds you want to draw your snapshot 
        let offset:CGFloat = 10
        

        let frame = cell.bounds.union(CGRect(x:-offset * 2.0,y:-offset * 2.0,
                          width:cell.bounds.width,
                          height: cell.bounds.height)).size 
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame, false ,0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.translateBy(x: offset, y: offset);
        cell.layer.render(in: context!)
        let snapshotImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       
        return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
}
```